# Qr Code reader is scanning two times how to make it as one successful scan only

Tags: android, qr-code

I followed [this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/tree/master/QR-ReaderExample) to read Qr code...

Over there I have added a scan button to start qr reader activity...and I am displaying Results on another page...

and now I am passing those result to server in a JOSN...so that Server Will response if its scanned first time update success..
and removed success.. like that..

But when I am trying I am getting both at a time in my database..
Here after first scan it should redirect to json page and display server status...

But Its still running and I am getting Both update and remove at time.. & getting result removed success every time..

I am doing this after scanning qr code to passing result..

```
Qrdata.this.finish();
Intent i = new Intent(this, json.class);
i.putExtra("qrdata", sdata);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(i);
```

But Its scanning two times...  before showing server response and displaying always removed success..

When I force move device form qr code at a moment I am getting Update success..

I want to stop qrscan after one successful scan..

can any one suggest me I will Update my code if any additional information required... on this qrcode..

Upate :

This is on server side..

```
    public class Sdata extends Activity {
    private static String urlString;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

                final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

            String rdata;
            Intent i = getIntent();
            rdata = i.getStringExtra("sdata");

                    tv.setText("");
                    urlString = "http://"+rdata;
                    new ProcessJSON().execute(urlString);

            System.out.println("****url****"+urlString);

        }
        
    }

    private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings){
            String stream=null;
            String urlString = strings[0];

            HDH hh = new HDH();
            stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);
            return stream;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String stream) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject key = new JSONObject(stream);
                    JSONObject response = key.getJSONObject("response");
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\t"+ status + "\n");

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait for a While.. Don't Go back .!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Can any one tell me where I need to add

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain it by flag like first check with boolean variable as

```
boolean scan = true;
if(scan) {
   //  ...scan qr..
}
```

and when you get result first time make that boolean false.

Comment: I my code where I need to Add this...I mean at Button or QR read or server side

Comment: put it before you request to server.

Comment: ok sir I am passing QR code in a Intent I will Update my server Side,.. Please update ur answer

Comment: sir now tell me where I need to change

Comment: i think there shoul be overriden function like this
@Override
 public void onQRCodeRead(String text, PointF[] points) {
  
 }

Comment: yes sir.. so is there any solution... In that overridden function I am using intent

Comment: put that whole intent code under that `if..` condition.